# Extract values from Rasters in R based on spatial points and spatial polygons

Tags: raster, r, buffer, extract

I am trying to extract values from a raster file using the `extract` command in R mentioned here:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/extract

My raster file is unprojected (WGS84 geographic coordinate system) and my points are in decimal degrees. I would like to extract the mean value in 10km buffers. I consider two approaches:

1) based on spatial points/buffering on the fly:

```
extract(rasterfile, pointsfile, method='simple', buffer=10000, small=FALSE, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

2) based on a spatial polygons (buffered shpfile created using ArcMap):

```
extract(rasterfile, buffershpfile, method='simple', small=FALSE, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

However, the answers that I get from these approaches are not the same and the differences are not trivial. It appears that values from (2) are more accurate than those from (1).

Am I doing something wrong or is this to be expected because of reasons mentioned here? [Extraction of raster cell values based on 'rgeos' and 'raster' buffering approaches in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60720/extraction-of-raster-cell-values-based-on-rgeos-and-raster-buffering-approac)

Comment: With buffering in R (gBuffer), you need to define the number of 'quadsegs', that is how many line segments the buffer is made up of. The default is quite a low number in R. This differs somewhat from buffer creation via ArcMap.